# Objective-c multiple delegates in the same view - ECSlidingViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ecslidingviewcontroller

I started testing [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController/tree/master/ECSlidingViewController) and after I tried to access `FirstTopViewController` I have a big trouble - because in `FirstToViewController` I already have [ZBarReaderDelegate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/)  implemented and all examples of delegate are not triggering any method from my delegate.

Basically I have this stuff:

## FirstTopViewController.h

```
#import ...MyStuff...
#import "UnderRightViewController.h"

@interface FirstTopViewController : UIViewController <RightViewDelegate, ZBarReaderDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *labelTotal; 

@end
```

## FirstTopViewController.m

```
#import "FirstTopViewController.h"

@implementation FirstTopViewController
- (void)setTotalViewController:(UnderRightViewController*)controller didTotalChange:(NSString*)total
{
    //labelTotal.text = total;
    NSLog(@"I'm here!!! and received %@", total);
}
```

From other side I have

## UnderRightViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"

@class UnderRightViewController;

@protocol RightViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)setTotalViewController:(UnderRightViewController*)controller didTotalChange:(NSString*)total;

@end

@interface UnderRightViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <RightViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

## UnderRightViewController.m

```
#import "UnderRightViewController.h"

@interface UnderRightViewController ()

@end

@implementation UnderRightViewController

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [delegate setTotalViewController:self didTotalChange:@"foo"];
}
@end
```

I'm trying this entire day solve this puzzle but I never get `setTotalViewController` fired.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you pasted the files from this ESSlidingViewController, did you include them in the "Build Phases" direction? Futhermore you could try to put the implementation of the UnderRichtVC in the main file of the firstTopVC!!

Comment: Did you set the delegate?

Comment: I have updated your code please follow??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friend you did a small mistake, when you navigate from `FirstTopViewController` to UnderRightViewController at that time you need to do this in FirstTopViewController.m:-

```
 UnderRightViewController *obj = [[UnderRightViewController
                                                                  alloc] initWithNibName:@"UnderRightViewController" bundle:nil];

obj.delegate  = self; // u forget to assign protocol handler


[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];


[obj release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any code that is setting the delegate for the UnderRightViewController. I don't know what object owns both of these controllers, but before either UnderRightViewController and FirstTopViewController are displayed it should run code something like this:

```
FirstTopViewController *ftvc = //... where ever you get a reference to this from
UnderRightViewController *urvc = ...;
urvc.delegate = ftvc;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your above code you are using custom delegates and also you have used it for sending message to onecontroller class to another controller class. So below is the same sample code of custom delegates, it is working fine in similar way you have to implement and also the problem in your code is you are not setting the delegate, so please follow below how to set the same and call the method. here i have used your same method only return type i have defined as `NSString` in-spite of `void` for explaining purpose, but you can use `void` according to your requirement hope it will be helpful to you:-

First Controller Class `AWindowController.h`

```
 @interface AWindowController : NSWindowController<sampleDelegate>

    {
        NSString *textA;
    }
    @property(readwrite,retain)NSString *textA;
    -(IBAction)doSet:(id)sender;
    @end

#import "AWindowController.h"
#import "BWindowController.h"

@interface AWindowController ()
@end
@implementation AWindowController
@synthesize textA;

- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSString *)setTotalViewController:(BWindowController*)controller didTotalChange:(NSString*)total
{
    NSLog(@"recieved");
    return @"recieved";
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
}

-(NSString*)windowNibName
{
    return @"AWindowController";
}

-(IBAction)doSet:(id)sender
{
    [self setTextA:@"Awindow Button Pressed"];
    BWindowController *b=[[BWindowController alloc]init];
    b.delegate=self;
    [b showWindow:self];
}
@end
```

Second Controller Class `BWindowController.h`

```
     #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
    #import "sampleDelegate.h"
    @class BWindowController;
    @protocol sampleDelegate <NSObject>
    @required
    //-(NSString *)getDataValue;
    - (NSString *)setTotalViewController:(BWindowController*)controller didTotalChange:(NSString*)total;
    @end
    @interface BWindowController : NSWindowController<sampleDelegate>
    {
        NSString *bTextValue;
        id<sampleDelegate>delegate;
    }
    @property(readwrite,retain)NSString *bTextValue;
    @property(readwrite,assign)id<sampleDelegate>delegate;
    @end


  #import "BWindowController.h"
@interface BWindowController ()

@end
@implementation BWindowController
@synthesize bTextValue,delegate;
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}
- (NSString *)setTotalViewController:(BWindowController*)controller didTotalChange:(NSString*)total;
{
    return nil;
}
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    NSString *str= [[self delegate]setTotalViewController:self didTotalChange:@"recieved"];
    self.bTextValue=str;
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
}

-(NSString*)windowNibName
{
    return @"BWindowController";
}

@end
```

Attached screen shot in Output:-
Below is window is the `AwindowController.h` class 
[image]

Below in the same above window pressing the button and when Awindow button pressed data will send
and notification will be recieved in Bwindow using above define custom delegates as attached in the screen shot.
[image]